# Android Eclipse: How do you save an image From the gallery to an App

Tags: android, imageview

I'm having trouble saving an image to my app. I have a button in an Activity that open up my gallery. I select a picture and that picture displays on screen in an imageView. Everything is fine as long as I stay on that screen. When I change screens and go back the image is gone. How do I go about getting that image to stay? (The image will be used as a "profile pic/avatar" that the user can choose themselves using an image from the gallery). **First time posting on stack overflow..sorry if I did anything wrong.

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Answer (score -1):

Each time your Activity goes out of screen, it will be stopped and may get destroyed. So  each time you return to your activity, there is a chance that it get re-started from the beginning. That means your onCreate() method is being called(most likely) again. You can learn about Android Activity Life Cycle here. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Applications in android doesn't work in the same way as you expect in desktop operating system. Your Activity can get destroyed at any time or your Activity can be called to display at anytime.

Of course you can save information about the image chosen by the user last time. But you need to be aware of Android Activity life cycles first.

In fact you can save information of user's choice and load it next time the Activity is created.

If you want to make sure that your activity can display the image even after it is moved or deleted, then you can copy it to a Cache folder or store it inside SQLite database(though storing images in SQlite database is not recommended). Instead of cacheing the actual image, you may create a low resolution version of it using BitmapFactory class.

Android-Universal-Image-Loader library worth a look https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader.

Comment: -1 for false statement "So in simple terms, each time you return to your activity, its re-started from the beginning". This **might** happen, can be **forced** to happen, but in most cases is not.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski You are right.But asker seems to be new to Android Development and such answer might create confusion.

Comment: Hmm... That seem's odd. You say "There is no such thing as saving an image to your app". So how do facebook and twitter profile pictures work? That's the exact same thing I'm trying to do. I found something about byte information of the image and something about putting the image in a database. Either one of those seem probable for accomplishing this?